# UITableView not displaying at runtime when embedded in a Container View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

This is my first time using TableView's and I've already hit a road block.

I've got a View Controller with a Container inside. The Container View has an embedded Table View Controller. I have populated the table view controller using the below code. I have set the datasource and the delegate to the Table View Controller, set the Custom Class of the Table View controller to ORMTableVC and set the Table View cell Identifier to cellIdentifier.

My problem is at runtime the View Controller is just blank and I cannot see any Table lines or data.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ORMTableVC : UITableViewController {




let cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier"

var Array = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   Array = ["Reps", "Weight", "RPE", "Fatigue", "Potential Max", "Fatigue Weight"]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return Array.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

Cell.textLabel?.text = Array[indexPath.row]

return Cell
}




}
```

[StoryBoard Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGGid.png)

[Built App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXHOV.png)

Answer (score 0):

After looking through many tutorials managed to fix this. Seemed like the code wasn't the issue it was the storyboard setup.

On the Table View Cell the identifier needed to be cellIdentifier not Cell.